# Ubuntu 21.04 Wayland copy/paste intermittently fails

Tags: wayland, 21.04, copy-and-paste, electron

Ubuntu 21.04
Gnome 3.38.5
Wayland

I've noticed that intermittently copy/paste starts failing. Anecdotally this only seems to happen when trying to paste into an electron app (slack/atom) but after that affects other applications too. Haven't found a way to reproduce it on demand though.

Not entirely a duplicate but this suggests similar behaviour [Copy-Paste from Firefox 88.0.1 not working properly on Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338970/copy-paste-from-firefox-88-0-1-not-working-properly-on-ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hip)

Comment: 21.04 is a test release so its not unexpected that you will see problems..   You might do better to fall back to the current LTS (Long Term support) version which is 20.04.
Then again Walland is a work in progress so don't hold your breath..

Comment: copy of e.g. file name from Nautilus and paste in e.g. emacs is affected as well, so I do not think this is an electron issue. Switching back to Xserver for now seems reasonable ;)

Comment: I have the same issue in 20.04 LTS Gnome 3.36.9 (Wayland)